# Discover IP address of the device knowing only MAC address

Tags: security, ip-address, wireshark, arp, mac-address

While "*wiresharking*" the network, You may come across packets that looks like
[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTaao.png)
`eth.src` to `eth.dst` (mainly colored white).. sometimes ***Wireshark*** recognize protocol **LLC**, **NDP** etc..
but sometimes it just `0x000` or `0x0de`. So You know the MAC address of sender but don't know IP address.

My question is 1:
How You can link it's MAC address to some IP? What in my head is just `nmap -sn` all the subnet then textual search for a MAC... but maybe there is more clever way or tool. I tried to use **arping**, but it seems to be not for this purpose.
question 2:
Let's imagine that a frame came from another subnet or VLAN ( is it possible? maybe in a very misconfigured network? if not why? ) - have we still have a chance to negotiate to a device and somehow and discover it's IP?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be an IP address for a given MAC. Not all layer 2 frames are IP.

Wireshark identified that as [ieee1905](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1905), specifically a topology discovery frame. Indeed, [01-80-C2-00-00-13 is registered to ieee1905](https://standards.ieee.org/products-services/regauth/grpmac/public.html).

Obviously, many other frames contain IP. Capture enough packets, and you may see IPv6 neighbor discovery or IPv4 ARP, associating IPs with layer 2.

When an address is not known to you, find the port it connects to on your switches. Find the physical device, and manage it.